# Drawing tools in C# + library code or component

Tags: c#, frameworks, drawing, draw

Can any one introduce me a code library or framework to use for drawing in C# like 
DRAWCLI Sample in VC++ ?
thx

Comment: Would it be ok if the tool were written in VB.NET?

Answer (score 3):

[System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) provides you with some [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions.

Comment: excuse me , i must said professional code library for drawing that can 
implementing of drawing and selection tools, objects selection, managing of objects Z-order etc
thx and sorry